# Angular2 - why instance of subject is placed inside the ngOninit?

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-observables

I am using the following code from angular.io website. for getting searched observables.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown-suggestion',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-suggestion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown-suggestion.component.css']
})
export class DropdownSuggestionComponent implements OnInit {

    userSuggestions: Observable<User[]>;
  userSuggestionsLoad: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(protected apiService: ApiService,) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userSuggestions = this.userSuggestionsLoad
      .debounceTime(300)        // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
      .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search term is same as previous
      .switchMap(term => this.apiService.search(term))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.of<User[]>([]);
      });
  }

  searchUsers(term) {
    const url = this.url + term ;
    this.userSuggestionsLoad.next(url);
  }
```

I want to understand why `this.userSuggestionsLoad` is placed inside the `ngOninit` always and if i place this outside it doesn't work.

I want to understand this as I want to make this functionality as base component and want to extend this component in my other component. but in that case `this.userSuggestionsLoad` is not getting triggered may be because of `ngOninit`.

Comment: post a link to the place where you found this code

Comment: https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to write this.userSuggestionsLoad implementation inside ngOnInit since it is lifecycle hook and call during component init. Here we need to implement subject since it is observable and we usually registered observable once and it get called when anything changed in it.

Now if you need your implementation avaibale inside child component you do as below:

```
export class DropdownSuggestionComponent implements OnInit {

    userSuggestions: Observable<User[]>;
  userSuggestionsLoad: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(protected apiService: ApiService,) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userSuggestions = this.userSuggestionsLoad
      .debounceTime(300)        // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
      .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search term is same as previous
      .switchMap(term => this.apiService.search(term))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.of<User[]>([]);
      });
  }


Now extending with another component

export class ChildComponent extends DropdownSuggestionComponent implement OnInit {

ngOnInit(): void {
super.ngOnInit(); // This code will call your parent class onInit which you want to execute
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The reason is that When the component loads up after the `constructor`
>   the `ngOnInit` life cycle hook is called.

The order of lyfecycle hooks

[image]

For more info on it [Link](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

If you want to place the `load` outside you have to place it inside a method that is manually triggered by the user from a template or any other component.

> [or in other lifecycle hook event]

**UDPATE**

if you want to manually trigger the function you need to create a method in the component like

```
call(){
 // the body
}
```

and call this from a template or any other component, like

```
<button (click) = "call" > Call Method </button>
```

or

```
let comp = new <componentName> ();
comp.call();
```

Comment: I am aware about the order of lifecycles. I want to know why userSuggestionsLoad is placed inside the ngoninit only why not in other function and how to manually trigger that function. can you give me sample. and can i have this functionality common so that i can reuse in all other components

Comment: hi, in this case i am calling the function searchUsers(term) to trigger the search term change. this case is somewhat tricky here i am placing the this.userSuggestionsLoad inside the ngOninit which will be called only once in the component but still it works fine if i use this directly in the component. in this case i am trying to use this in separate component so that i can extend that component and reuse it. but in then it fails in its purpose. it is triggering the search term change but not triggering the api call.

Comment: Make use of services if you want this to be global @SunilKumar

Comment: in services i cant use ngOninit. this.userSuggestionsLoad has to be put in ngOninit only other wise it wont work.  reply: yes i want to use this many component.

Comment: @SunilKumar put in a service and also place child routes and use router resolve

Comment: we cannot use service as it works only with ngOninit.

Comment: that is is reason i am telling you to use child routes and router resolve it will be called before each component

Comment: i dont know how to use them can you give me knowledge base to find if i can use them. more suitably i want to understand about the subject. why i need to place that function inside the ngOninit only. how subject works.